# Ошибка в вызове функции

Tags: функции, функциональное-программирование, lisp

Я начал изучать Lisp по книге Питера Сайбеля, "Практическое использование Common Lisp", создавая по примеру базу данных я столкнулся с проблемой, такой код:

```lisp
(defvar *db* nil)

(defun dump-db ()
  (format t "~a:~10t~a~%~%" *db*))

(dump-db)
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
*** - APPLY: слишком мало аргументов для #<COMPILED-FUNCTION DUMP-DB-1>
```

Прежде чем задать вопрос, я почитал о чём пишут на других ресурсах, но моей ситуации не нашёл.

P. S. Вместо Lisp in a Box, как в книге, я использую gnu clisp + vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какой версией clisp вы пользуетесь? У меня `GNU CLISP 2.49.60+` выводит вполне понятное сообщение:

```
*** - There are not enough arguments left for this format directive.
      Current point in control string:
        "~a:~10t~a~%~%"
                |
```

Директива `~a` печатает значение аргумента, `~10t` выводит табуляцию до колонки 10, `~%` печатает перевод строки. У вас в формате две директивы `~a` и всего один аргумент. Попробуйте так:

```lisp
(defun dump-db ()
  (format t "~a:~10t~a~%~%" "*DB*" *db*))
```

Comment: Я использую ```GNU CLISP 2.49 (2010-07-07)```. Есть ли версия новее? Просто пользоваться программой 2010 года, как то не очень.

Comment: Да, clisp замер в своём развитии. Он настолько гибкий, что развиваться некуда )) У меня тоже версия 2.49

Answer (score 1):

Макрос `format` читает список аргументов и заменяет ими поля в контрольной строке.

Для вашего случая подойдет `~1:*` - вернутся на один шаг назад по списку аргументов и применить его снова.

```
(defvar *db* nil)

(defun dump-db ()
"Дублирует каждый аргумент дважды."
 (format t "~a:~t~1:*~%" *db*))
```

```
CL-USER> (dump-db)
NIL NIL
```

**Ссылки**

- https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node200.html